# Margin on many inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of images having `inline-block` display type within a fixed width div.

The images have a margin of `0 5px 5px 0` which means you get a nice table effect when you have many of them.

Unfortunately this creates a side effect where the containing div has extra space between the images and its padding at the bottom and right.

How can I fix this?

**CSS**

```
div{
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 191px;
    background: #ddd;
}
img {
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 23px;
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;

    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

[Fiddlesis](http://jsfiddle.net/LnHDc/)

Comment: Please post example HTML & CSS

Comment: @Paulie_D Look at the link at the bottom of the question

Comment: I'm sure you've been here long enough to know that a Fiddle isn;t usually enough. Posting the HTML/CSS allows users to see the basic issue in case the fiddle gets deleted. : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/NY6E2/)

Change your `div`'s `padding` to this:

> > padding:10px 5px 0 10px;

Comment: What kei said -- beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick approach could be to simply justify align with margins of `auto` for right and left and vertical align middle:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/LnHDc/3/)

```
div{
    padding: 10px 10px 5px;
    max-width: 191px;
    background: #ddd;
    text-align:justify;
}
img {
max-width: 30px;
min-height: 23px;
    margin:0 auto 5px auto;
    vertical-align:middle;    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This looks great on the fiddle but interestingly enough I cannot get it to work with my CSS / HTML

Answer (score 0):

rearrange padding for your div and set image as vertical-align:top or bottom to erase the gap under it .

```
div{
    padding: 10px 10px 5px;
    max-width: 191px;
    background: #ddd;
}
img {
max-width: 30px;
min-height: 23px;
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;
    vertical-align:top;      
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LnHDc/1/

Else dispatch margin and padding and see how to deal with white-space (code not indented, use of comment, font-size to 0 , .... ) http://jsfiddle.net/LnHDc/4 or http://jsfiddle.net/LnHDc/5 or http://jsfiddle.net/LnHDc/6 .
you have many ways to approach this, eeven floatting image .

Comment: That still gives a wider gap between the sheep and the div on the right than on the left

Comment: if you draw a grid behind, it is easier to check out how it looks : http://jsfiddle.net/LnHDc/12/